# Unable to create order in kucoin futures from python

Tags: python, api, kucoin

I was wondering how i can create kucoin futures order with python.
Any help would be appreciated

I tried kucoin-futures documentation but it did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having issues with the limit order for KuCoin futures.

I've posted another question here, but the code is essentially working an you'll be able to use for your needs I believe :)
[Issue with KuCoin Futures API to create limit order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522901/issue-with-kucoin-futures-api-to-create-limit-order)